# Freeing up memory by deleting a vector in a vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector of vectors and I wish to delete myvec[i] from memory entirely, free up the room, and so on. Will .erase or .clear do the job for me? If not, what should I do?

Comment: Please could you show some real code?

Comment: I am not sure what code there is to show. I am asking how to delete/free up the memory for a subvector. for example vector< vector<int> > myvec; and I wish to free the contents of some arbitrary myvec[i]

Comment: use [erase remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom), then you should be fine. If vector contains pointer, you need to release the memory the pointer is pointing to first.

Comment: seems like erase remove idiom requires knowing what value to remove. i just want to get rid of the entire subvector

Comment: oh I see, have a try with yzt's answer should work.

Comment: @billz That's not a good idea. The OP obviously wants to `clear` the vector and deallocate the memory that vector internally has. using `remove` and even erasing all the elements or `clear`ing the vector are not guaranteed to do that.

Comment: @juanchopanza A call to `erase` only destructs the erased elements and changes the size of the vector. It might not actually change the capacity of the vector (i.e. the size of the underlying block of memory used by the vector) and therefore, it might not deallocate any memory. This (not deallocating/allocatating memory on every call to `push_back`, `pop_back`, `erase`, etc.) is done as a very important and essential optimization.

Comment: @yzt You are completely right. I will remove that comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Completely Removing The Vector

If you want to completely remove the vector at index `i` in your `myvec`, so that `myvec[i]` will no longer exist and `myvec.size()` will be one less that it was before, you should do this:

```
myvec.erase (myvec.begin() + i); // Note that this only works on vectors
```

This will completely deallocate all memories owned by `myvec[i]` and will move all the elements after it (`myvec[i + 1]`, `myvec[i + 2]`, etc.) one place back so that `myvec` will have one less vector in it.

## Emptying But Keeping The Vector

However, if you don't want to remove the `i`th vector from `myvec`, and you just want to completely empty it while keeping the empty vector in place, there are several methods you can use.

### Basic Method

One technique that is commonly used is to `swap` the vector you want to empty out with a new and completely empty vector, like this:

```
// suppose the type of your vectors is vector<int>
vector<int>().swap (myvec[i]);
```

This is *guaranteed* to free up all the memory in `myvec[i]`, it's fast and it doesn't allocate any new heap memory or anything.

This is used because the method `clear` does not offer such a guarantee. If you `clear` the vector, it always does set its size to zero and destruct all the elements, but it might not (depending on the implementation) actually free the memory.

In C++11, you can do what you want with two function calls: (thanks for the helpful comment)

```
myvec[i].clear();
myvec[i].shrink_to_fit();
```

### Generalization

You can write a small function that would work for most (probably all) STL containers and more:

```
template <typename T>
void Eviscerate (T & x)
{
    T().swap (x);
}
```

which you use like this:

```
Eviscerate (myvec[i]);
```

This is obviously cleaner and more readable, not to mention more general.

In C++11, you can also use `decltype` to write a generic solution (independent of the type of your container and elements,) but it's very ugly and I only put it here for completeness:

```
// You should include <utility> for std::remove_reference
typename std::remove_reference<decltype(myvec[i])>::type().swap(myvec[i]);
```

My recommended method is the `Eviscerate` function above.

Comment: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<int>::swap(std::vector<int>)' and no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::vector<int>' to 'std::vector<int>&'

Comment: Oh, right! Stupid mistake on my part. It should be the other way around. I'll edit.

Comment: Depending on what you perceive as the most readable, you might want `myvec[i].clear(); myvec[i].shrink_to_fit();`.

Comment: @chris Actually, `myvec.erase( myvec.begin() + 1 )` sounds more like what he wants.

Comment: @JamesKanze Doesn't seem so to me. I think OP wants to clear the vector and deallocate its memory.

Comment: @yzt He says he wants to remove `myvec[i]` completely from memory.  That would be `myvec.erase( myvec.begin() + i )`.  Swapping `myvec[i]` with an empty vector will still leave `myvec[i]` in `myvec`.  Empty, and with no dynamically allocated memory (in practice, anyway), but still present.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Oh, right! I had misread your function call! But in my defense, the question was not entirely clear. Do you mind if I add your point to my answer? I think the description about emptying a vector can be useful and beneficial to some people so I will keep it.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I wonder why the OP accepted my answer (and some other people voted it up) considering the fact that I had misunderstood the question! (Anyways, I up-voted your comments and answer.)

Comment: @yzt No problem if you add it.  And I don't think that the OP was really that clear about what he wanted, either.

Answer (score 1):

`myvec.erase( myvec.begin() + i )` will remove `myvec[i]`
completely, calling its destructor, and freeing all of its
dynamically allocated memory.  It will *not* reduce the memory
used directly by `myvec`: `myvec.size()` will be reduced by one,
but `myvec.capacity()` will be unchanged.  To remove this last
residue, C++11 has `myvec.shrink_to_fit()`, which *might* remove
it; otherwise, you'll have to make a complete copy of `myvec`, 
then swap it in:

```
void
shrink_to_fit( MyVecType& target )
{
    MyVecType tmp( target.begin(), target.end() );
    target.swap( tmp );
}
```

(This is basically what `shring_to_fit` will do under the hood.)
This is a very expensive operation, for very little real gain,
at least with regards to the removal of single elements; if you
are erasing a large number of elements, it might be worth
considering it after all of the erasures.

Finally, if you want to erase all of the elements,
`myvec.clear()` is exactly the same as `myvec.erase()` on each
element, with the same considerations described above.  In this
case, creating an empty vector and swapping is a better
solution.